# Show most popular QUERY_STRING

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that shows data from my database.  Before the user sees the data they have a few select boxes so they can choose to filter the data in a number of different ways eg to chose to show data over a certain period of time. and the url looks similar to the below as I am using the get method.

```
http://www.example/com?report=2&days=7&etc=2
```

This all works fine and the users can filter the data to get the different results that they want.  I have been viewing my analytics account and can see that some queries are more popular than others. How can I let the users know which queries are the most popular (eg most viewed over the last 24 hours). Currently I have made a manual html table that I update in the morning based on the Analytics data.

eg

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><th>query</th><th>link</th></tr>
<tr><td>Show data from last 7 days</td><td><a href="http://www.example/com?report=2&days=7&etc=2">View</a></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I thought about adding a table called count which has id, query, timestamp and saying

```
$a='report=';
$b=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
if($b == $a . $report['id'])
{}
else
{//Insert id, query, timestamp into the database}
```

This way I can do a count for a certain time period on queries that have the additional sorting paremeters. Is this the best way to acheive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a table that stores the query-part of the url and the timestamp. It needs no other fields as you'll get a running sum of the latest calls.

Then get something like

```
select url, 
       count(*) as reqs 
  from queries 
 where ts > now() - interval 24 hour 
 group by url 
 order by reqs desc
```

to get the most requested urls for the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go a bit more and take into consideration the followings:

```
http://www.example/com?report=2&days=7&etc=2
```

is basically the same as:

```
http://www.example/com?report=2&etc=2&days=7
```

with regards to what it expresses, but the algorithm you mentioned will record them as 2 different reports because `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];` is different.

Also, from your apps business logic perspective, extra parameters might not be used, but present:

```
http://www.example/com?report=2&etc=2&days=7&utm_source=feed
```

So, I'd do a little processing on the params that form the key for query:

1. sort by param name
2. Only take into consideration the params that actually matter

Comment: Probably a waste of time since the OP has control over the gui that generates the query.

Comment: And you think that in 1 month he will remember to keep the URLs the same when he'll have to add some new features to that page? Or a colleague that is adding/updating functionalities on those pages?

Comment: I don't think it matters as the running sum will be over just 24 hours.

Comment: You are basing your statements on some wrong assumptions: 1 - the reports will not change/evolve in the future (it rarely happens that); 2 - everybody involved in the development will be aware of the need to keep the parameters fixed as order and number. 3 - the reports are for 24hrs when the ops says they are for the last 7 days. Your explanations make sense within a strict set of rules, but my guidelines are not that hard or time consuming to implement in order to impose those constraints

Comment: No, 7 days is part of the query. OP says "(eg most viewed over the last 24 hours)" and that is my assumption. Also, "I have _a_ page ... select a few boxes". That leads me to think that the order will indeed be fixed. If those change then you are correct in that sorting might be helpful. I think that an initial approach always should be kept as simple as possible.

Comment: Both make some valid points here. I hadn't considered the possibility of the different string for the same report as I was controlling the form, currently I only have the daily most popular in mind but it is also good to consider other time periods down the track.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should create a table with timestamp, report, days, etc and use those as a key.

This is much safer, if:

- anytime parameters may be sent by POST (form) they won't be in the url.
- anytime some of them might come from COOKIES or other sources they won't be in the url.
- you decide to add other options to the URL that may change from page to page but won't modify the kind of report shown, like styling options such as &viewkind=2&colorset=3 or add random to invalidate cache like &rnd=83732 or anything else you may decide in the future.
- anything else added to the url like hashes #name may interfere (jumping to named anchor in half bottom of page will be considered a different report)
- also, forging a full URL to attack your database is probably much easier than forging the single integer or string name parameters
- also your site may be called in different ways that make the url different. With www in front or without, with https if secure. Some parameters may have default values, so for instance not specifying days might be the same as, say, days=1 so the report might be the same but URL different.